# Is there a list of other values besides " ", and "-" that are invalid for components in Inno Setup?

Tags: inno-setup

In Inno Setup, within the name of a component, the '-' value is not valid is there a list of other values besides " " that are invalid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rules for the `Name` parameter values of the `[Tasks]` and `[Components]` sections are:

- the first char must be an alpha char from range A-Z (case does not matter), or an underscore
- what follows must be an alpha char from range A-Z (case does not matter), an underscore, a number, or a slash (forward or backward) used as a component level delimiter
- the name must not be any of these reserved words - `not`, `and`, `or`

Comment: Very helpful as always, +1. I assume that slashes are not allowed in Tasks since they are not Components.

Comment: There is no difference in those rules for the mentioned sections. I've composed these rules from the source. You can see [`here`](https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/blob/master/Projects/Compile.pas#L4567) how the `Name` parameter for the `[Components]` section is processed and validated, and [`here`](https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/blob/master/Projects/Compile.pas#L4670) for the `[Tasks]` section. They are both processed the very same way.

Answer (score 1):

If you compile a .iss file with a component with a dash, it will tell you that only alpha numeric chars are valid. In addition it will also tell you that it may not start or end with a '\' or '/'. (tho '/' and '\' are special chars and are valid to denote the level of the component. Also a component value or 
"not", "and" or "or" are reserved.

Comment: My answer is missing the underscore. Bonus points to TLama for including Tasks even though I did not mention them.